# ProducerConfig for FlinkKafkaProducer with exactly-once semantics

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When creating a Kafka producer with exactly-once semantics using the Kafka API, two properties have to be set: `transactional.id` has to be set to a transactional id, and `enable.idempotence` has to be set to true.

In Apache Flink, a `FlinkKafkaProducer` can be configured with a parameter for the desired semantics of the producer, in particular with the value `Semantics.EXACTLY_ONCE` for exactly once semantics.

Looking at the source code of the `FlinkKafkaProducer`, transactional ids are automatically generated and maintained. However, I did not found any place where `enable.idempotence` is set to true for the `ProducerConfig` of the underlying `KafkaProducer`.

Does the property `enable.idempotence` have to be provided in the `ProducerConfig` given to the `FlinkKafkaProducer`, or is there something I have overseen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't need to be set as stated in the [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html):

> If the transactional.id is set, idempotence is automatically enabled along with the producer configs which idempotence depends on.

And as you noticed, after selecting `Semantics.EXACTLY_ONCE` Flink is taking care of setting and controlling `transactional.id` property.

However there are a couple of other properties that you might be interested [mentioned here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#data-loss). I'm not sure how is it now, but as I checked last time default Kafka brokers/clients configuration was actually allowing for data loss to happen in some scenarios.

Comment: how can I override `transaction.id` property?

Comment: You can not. Keep in mind that Flink is not using a single `transactional.id` but each parallel instance of a `FlinkKafkaProducer` is using its own pool of those. I think by default that pool's size is 5. For example with parallelism of 12, that gives 60 `transactional.id` being used by a single job.

You can also take a look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11654

Comment: ty for more information. Fortunately in my case to pass ssl certificate,  `transaction.id` prefix is enough. Flink is using task name + uid as kafka producer transaction id prefix